# Cross validation where either in or out sample is missing some categories in a categorical variable

Tags: cross-validation

Consider a sample data set:

```
+---------+----------------+
|   Sex   | Likes Icecream |
+---------+----------------+
| M       | Y              |
| F       | Y              |
| M       | N              |
| F       | Y              |
| Unknown | N              |
| Unknown | N              |
| Unknown | Y              |
+---------+----------------+
```

I am interested in cross validating a model which tries to predict "Likes Icecream" based on the value for sex.

Now, suppose we do 2-fold cross validation, and you were unlucky enough to have the following two in and out-sample datasets for the first fold:

```
In-sample:

+-----+----------------+
| Sex | Likes Icecream |
+-----+----------------+
| M   | Y              |
| F   | Y              |
| M   | N              |
+-----+----------------+

Out-sample:

+---------+----------------+
|   Sex   | Likes Icecream |
+---------+----------------+
| F       | Y              |
| Unknown | N              |
| Unknown | N              |
| Unknown | Y              |
+---------+----------------+
```

and suppose we fit a logistic regression. Now, on the in-sample data we would know how `Sex M/F` affects `Likes Icecream`. However, to measure this model on the out-sample data, we need to predict the value of `Likes Icecream`.

So what prediction do you give for `Sex = Unknown` in the out-sample data, or how do you measure the inaccuracy of the model on the out-sample data when `Sex = Unknown`?

Does it matter that you cannot measure the inaccuracy of the model on `Sex = Male` in the out-sample data?

Comment: This question on SO deals with the practical aspects of calling `predict.glm` in `R`. There is a answer that talks about coding the categorical variables as dummy binary variables which I believe should cover my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285214/predict-lm-with-an-unknown-factor-level-in-test-data